# Check for optional set of characters using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a date in the following format:

> October 4, 2019 10:30 am

This date needs to be broken apart into the month, day, year and time. Where the time is optional. So in other words, this should also be valid:

> October 4, 2019

Unfortunately if I do attempt to leave out the time from the string, I get undefined when using the following patter:

```
const match = /(\w+)( [^.]+)?, ([0-9]{4}) ((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-9]{2} (?:am|pm))?/.exec(dt);
```

I would expect this to work with or without the time part as I displayed in the example strings. I've looked for a few threads with the same issues and from my understanding, this should work with the `?`

So for this case, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This is great! And great site for learning Regex too. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space before the optional group is still obligatory, hence you have no match with the second string.

Put the space into the group:

```
/(\w+)( [^,]+)?, ([0-9]{4})( (?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-9]{2} (?:am|pm))?/ 
                            ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJJpWy/1).

Note I also think `[^.]+` must be `[^,]+`, any 1 or more chars other than a *comma*.

You may further shorten the pattern to

```
/(\w+)( [^,]+)?, (\d{4})( (?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):\d{2} [ap]m)?/
```

Note that it might be a good idea to replace literal spaces with `\s+` to match any 1+ whitespace and do not worry if there are hard or regular spaces in the input:

```
/(\w+)(\s+[^,]+)?,\s+(\d{4})(\s+(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):\d{2}\s+[ap]m)?/
```

Answer (score 1):

The commented solution above works, however it includes whitespace in the groups, which means if you use them as variables they'll have whitespace. The solution below should exclude all whitespaces from the groups.

```
(\w+) ([^,]+)?, ([0-9]{4})\s?([01]\d:\d\d+ am|pm)?
```